# How to subscribe AND publish at the same time with mosquitto command line tools?

Tags: command-line, mqtt, mosquitto

I want to implement a request-response with MQTT (3.1.1).
It can be done using some language binding I guess.
But how to do it using mosquitto_pub and mosquitto_sub command line utilities?

The main problem is, that i need to subscribe first, then publish, then wait for the incoming packet.
I tried this using zsh (or bash), with no luck, as you can see sometimes the message arrives, sometimes it does not.

```
$ mosquitto_sub -t topic -C 1 & mosquitto_pub -t topic -m message ; fg
[1] 20321
[1]  + running    mosquitto_sub -t topic -C 1
^C
$ mosquitto_sub -t topic -C 1 & mosquitto_pub -t topic -m message ; fg
[1] 20341
[1]  + running    mosquitto_sub -t topic -C 1
message
```

Also it does connect twice which is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mosquitto_rr

mosquitto_rr is an MQTT version 5/3.1.1 client that can be used to publish a request message and wait for a response. When using MQTT v5, which is the default, mosquitto_rr will use the Request-Response feature.

(from man mosquitto_rr)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to this is, you don't.

If you want to do this sort of thing use a proper client library with something like python.